# Is there any unique ID associated with each Powerpoint presentation file (.ppt or .pptx)?

Tags: vba, ms-office, powerpoint

I have checked MSDN and there seems to be no unique ID (UUID or whatnot) property in the `Presentation` object model ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff746640(v=office.15).aspx )

According to the code example, a Presentation can only be identified by a name only. e.g.

```
Presentations("Sample Presentation").Slides.Add 1, 1
```

Is there anyway I can identify a presentation by way of an ID? Hopefully it will looks something like this

```
Presentations("067e6162-3b6f-4abc-a171-2470b63dff00").Slides.Add 1, 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PowerPoint object model doesn't provide any special ID. You can use the [FullName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746313(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Presentation class to identify presentations uniquely.

If you are not satisfied with that solution you may consider adding your own ID as a custom document property. The [CustomDocumentProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744661(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Presentation class returns a DocumentProperties collection that represents all the custom document properties for the specified presentation.

Comment: Eugene's correct. Either a document property or a presentation level tag would allow you to add your own unique ID.  Note that FullName isn't foolproof.  C:\Temp\ThisFile.PPTX on my computer and on your computer could be entirely different presentations, but same FullName.  Or Anthony might need to be able to determine that a given file, no matter where it's stored or what it's named, is actually the file he's looking for.  FullName would fail again, but tags or doc props would work.  I prefer tags because the user won't be able to see/edit them.